# HTML including an input from one file to another

Tags: html

If you name an input from the user in one html file using  and  tags, how do you use it in another html file?? I want to use only html. No javascript or anything.

The main file:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
Harry Potter
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY text = "red" bgcolor = "green">
<CENTER><H1><B><U>Harry Potter</U></B></H1></CENTER>
Please register for HPhmR by <A href = form.html>Clicking Here</A>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Form.html:

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>
HPhmR Resgistering
</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY bgcolor = "turquoise">
<FORM action = "harry potter.html" method = "post" name = "HPhmR">
<P>Please enter your username : 
<INPUT type = "text" size = "30" name = "username" maxlength = "20">
</P>
<P>Please enter your password : 
<INPUT type = "password" size = "30" name = "password" maxlength = "15">
</P>
<P>Please choose your favourite character:<BR>
<SELECT name = "favcha" size = "8" MULTIPLE>
<OPTION value = "Dumbledore">Albus Dumbledore</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Voldemort">Lord Voldemort</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Harry">Harry Potter</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Ron">Ron Weasely</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Hermione">Hermione Granger</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Sirius">Sirius Black</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Bellatrix">Bellatrix Lestrange</OPTION>
<OPTION value = "Draco">Draco Malfoy</OPTION>
</SELECT>
</P>
<P>Select your age range : 
<INPUT type = "radio" name = "10-15" value = "1">10 to 15 yrs
<INPUT type = "radio" name = "15-20" value = "2">15 to 20 yrs
<INPUT type = "radio" name = "20-30" value = "3">20 to 30 yrs
<INPUT type = "radio" name = "30-45" value = "4">30 to 45 yrs
<INPUT type = "radio" name = "45-60" value = "5">45 to 60 yrs
<INPUT type = "radio" name = "60+" value = "6">Above 60 yrs
</P>
<INPUT type = "submit" value = "Submit and Register">
</FORM>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

How do I use the input from the user in form.html? I want to use that input and do something else in the main file.

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking.  Please elaborate, preferably with what you have tried so far.

Comment: Not sure you can reuse HTML elements from one file to another using only HTML. You would have to use some sort of component framework if you'd like to use reusable HTML elements in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that using just html.but you can use php or asp.net to send forms from one file to another.

Comment: How do you do that using php or asp.net?

Comment: Search the net especialy w3school.com